# Cannot draw shapes Rectangles, Paths... below EditText text

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext

I want to draw shapes Rectangles, Circle, Paths, Triangles below the text value of TextView and [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText). So I override the onDraw() method and tested it by drawing simple BLUE rectangle after setting the background color to GREEN. I know that I should not initialize object (Paint  object) inside the onDraw() method but it is for testing only. Below is the full code:

```
class Test : AppCompatEditText {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
 
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
 
        canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, 150f, 50f, Paint().apply {
            isAntiAlias = true
            color = Color.BLUE
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
        })

        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
}
```

And then initialize it using xml

```
 <com.slaviboy.galaxy.Test
     android:id="@+id/ssss"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="TEST"
     android:imeOptions="actionDone"
     android:inputType="number"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Here is the final result

[image]

Last time I have use similar code I remember it working especially for [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText)!

1. I am drawing a OpenGL scene using [GLSurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView) beneath all the view so I thought that was causing it, so I removed it but the problem remained.
2. Then I changed the type from EditText to simple [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) and it started worked as expected. So it indicated that it is problem caused only when I use EditText and the TextView.
3. So I started removing attributes from the xml initialization and in particular the attribute ***inputType***

So as soon as I removed the inputType attribute the code started working as expected,

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Any idea why it cases the view to lose all its drawing?
And is there a workaround around it?

I know that I can limit the letters allowed using the attribute ***digits***, but is there a way to keep the keyboard style to numbers?

```
android:digits="0123456789."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having is related to this issue: [Cannot draw on Chip when text alignment is center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327346/cannot-draw-on-chip-when-text-alignment-is-center). You can read through the accepted answer, but the bottom line is that *TextView* internal scrolling is off so, even though your drawing is taking place, it is scrolled out of view. The quick solution is to set horizontal scrolling to `false`.

```
class MyEditText : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{
    ...
    init {
        setHorizontallyScrolling(false)
    }
    ...
}
```

There may be unintended consequences to doing this but, if the *TextView* doesn't do anything fancy, I think you will be ok. There are other fixes mentioned in the answer such as capturing the scroll and scrolling back that may be safer.

Comment: Thank you, I have tested it and it works! But I found even better solution I set the attribute android:digits="0123456789.-" and it fixes it, you can test it out! But I will approve your answer for your commitment.

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance and upvote. Your simpler solution works for your situation, but the general problem is with the bad scrolling. This answer will work for other `inputTypes` where the problem also manifests itself as well as for the "number" `inputType` - just for future reference.